# How to sign up a user with Cognito User Pool - Amazon Web Services without username and password

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon Web Services to authenticating users for my iOS app.
I have a screen sign up with phone number. When user enter his phone number, he gets a OTP code, then, he will enter that code in Verify Screen. Finally, after verify correct, App push to Create Username & Password Screen. That's all I want.
But, Amazon web services only provide register method as below:

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * phone = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];
phone.name = @"phone_number";
//phone number must be prefixed by country code
phone.value = @"+15555555555";
AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * email = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];
email.name = @"email";
email.value = @"email@mydomain.com";

//register the user
[[pool signUp:@"username" password:@"password" userAttributes:@[email,phone] validationData:nil] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse *> * _Nonnull task) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(task.error){
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:task.error.userInfo[@"__type"]
                                        message:task.error.userInfo[@"message"]
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }else {
            AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse * response = task.result;
            if(!response.userConfirmed){
                //need to confirm user using user.confirmUser:
            }
        }});
    return nil;
}];
```

As you can see, I must create username and password when I register with phone number. But I want to create username and pass later. Who can help me to resolve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of January 9 2017, Amazon Cognito does not support the flow you have described.

If you reverse the flow you can do this with Cognito:
Sign Up with username, password and phone number -> app user receives a verification code -> app user submits verification code -> app user signed-up/in.

The user will only be able to sign in if the phone number they used was verified and 'auto verification' is turned on for phone number.

You can also use aliases to allow your users to sign in with their phone number:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-aliases

Comment: Thanks! It's also my last solution